# Echo inner join on two tables in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have **3 tables that i want to join together**. I have tried it in mysql and it works fine.

But i am unable to figure out **how to echo it in php**. 
Need help please.

```
________________________________________
            Table orders                
________________________________________
 id | user_id | pickup_id | shipping id 
________________________________________

______________
 Table pickup
______________ 
 id | address
______________

______________ 
Table shipping 
______________ 
 id | address
______________
```

**My php :**

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * 
         FROM orders 
         INNER JOIN pickup ON 'orders.pickup_id' = 'pickup.id' 
         INNER JOIN shipping ON 'orders.shipping_id' = 'shipping.id' "; 
$run_query1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1); 
$count1 = mysqli_num_rows($run_query1); 

    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query1)){ 
        echo '<pre>' . print_r( $row1, TRUE ) . '</pre>'; 
        echo $row1['address']; 
        echo $row1['id']; 
    }
```

**It outputs nothing**

Comment: Can you post your PHP code so we can tell you what you are doing wrong?

Comment: What **exactly** ist the problem with that code? Is there any error message you have not shared yet? And please add that code with proper formatting to your question, not to the comment section

Comment: kindly show your code @Omer Nadeem

Comment: There is no error message. It shows nothing.

Comment: you have a if that is completely unecessary. Remove it. Also, are you sure that the query should return results? Show the errors you get (either on screen or in the logs). Finally, add ALL the relevant code. This doesn't look to have issues.

Comment: Remove the single quotes from the fields you're trying to join

Comment: @Bart Removing the single quotes worked. Thank you so very much.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 0):

remove the inverted commas and put the on field in brackets

```
 $sql1 = "SELECT * 
             FROM orders 
             INNER JOIN pickup ON (orders.pickup_id = pickup.id) 
             INNER JOIN shipping ON (orders.shipping_id = shipping.id) "; 
    $run_query1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1); 
    $count1 = mysqli_num_rows($run_query1); 

        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query1)){ 
            echo '<pre>' . print_r( $row1, TRUE ) . '</pre>'; 
            echo $row1['address']; 
            echo $row1['id']; 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$sql1 = ("SELECT
 pickup.address as pickup_address , shipping.address as shipping_address, orders.*
FROM orders 
RIGHT JOIN pickup ON orders.pickup_id = pickup.id
RIGHT JOIN shipping ON  orders.shipping_id = shipping.id
");

 $run_query1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
 $count1 = mysqli_num_rows($run_query1);

  while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query1)){
   echo $row1['pickup_address']."</br>";
   echo $row1 ['shipping_address']."</br>";
  }
```